# MDT 2010 CustomSettings.ini for each task

Tags: windows-7, deployment, mdt-2010

Is there a way to define CustomSettings for each task? I have a task that is only to capture the User State of a machine, I want specify in the task/customsettings credentials to use and a location to save the state to. I want these credentials/settings to be task specific. I think there is an easy way to do this I just can't find it.

```
[Settings]
Priority=Default
Properties=MyCustomProperty

[Default]
OSInstall=Y
SkipAppsOnUpgrade=YES
SkipCapture=YES
SkipAdminPassword=YES
SkipProductKey=YES

[106]
UserID=xxxxx
UserDomain=xxxxx
UserPassword=xxxxx
```

I'd like my customsettings.ini to look something like this where task sequence 106 would get the settings under [106] or can I put a customsettings.ini in the task folder and get the correct behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer I was looking for
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/mdt/thread/84831d92-b69a-493b-8dc8-3e0efb419242/

Example:

```
[Settings]
Priority=TaskSequenceID, Default

[XP]
OSDComputerName=XP
SkipUserData=YES

[Default]
KeyboardLocale=en-us
UserLocale=en-us
UILanguage=en-us
```